# Why does CFileDialog::DoModal() Hang?

Tags: visual-c++

I have developed a fairly large C++ program in VS 6.0 on a Win XP platform, and have now migrated to a new machine running Win 7 (still running VS 6.0). The code includes a function to instantiate and run a CFileDialog object to find and open an ASCII file with a specific extension from a specific initial directory. But now, the program hangs on the line

```
if (t1.DoModal()==IDOK)
```

...where t1 is the CFileDialog instance. 
To investigate why the standard CfileDialog class stopped working, I created a separate test project in VS 6.0 with a simple dialog with one button, containing this code:

```
void CFileDialogTestDlg::OnOpenFileDialogButton() 
{
  CFileDialog t1(true);
  if(t1.DoModal()==IDOK)
  {
    CString s3=t1.GetPathName();
    MessageBox(s3);
  }
}
```

This test works fine and displays a useable file dialog. I can also duplicate what I want in my large project in terms of initial directory,etc by modifying the m_ofn members of t1.

But putting this code into my large project (ie modifying the relevant button in it) still hangs on the  `DoModal()`  line. It seems unproductive trying to trace into a standard MS class, the internals are impossible to understand in a reasonable timeframe.

When I increased stackspace for my test project to match my large project (400MB), I reproduced the hanging behaviour identical to the large project.

Can anyone explain why increasing stackspace should affect file dialog execution in this way, and is there a way around the problem, bearing in mind I need the large stackspace to avoid completely rewriting my project?

Comment: Is your real project using threading?

Comment: Yes, Debug Multithreaded DLL (Project settings)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the stack is your problem.  It's been a while but I seem to recall common modals hanging if you access them from the wrong thread.

Comment: You need to use a UI thread.  Check to see if you're calling the modal from a thread spun up that your program created.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b807sta6.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use [PostMessage() API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tdesxec.aspx) to send commands from any thread to the thread that owns the modal dialog. It needs to be the owning (and blocking) thread that ultimately receives the command to accept/cancel the dialog so that it returns from its *message pump* routine.

If you install the Windows debug symbols, you can see the full call stack of your blocking thread in a debugger.